# Размещение различных виджетов в листаемом виджете

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Как сделать так, чтобы каждый виджет шел друг за другом?

Я использовал ScrollView. Понятно, что я установил для каждого виджета вручную размер и это не правильно, потому как у текстового виджеа может быть размер и 25 пикселей и 100 и т.д. И поэтому мои виджеты попадают друг на друга. Есть некоторые сомнения, что для этого лучше использовать не ScrollView. Я не знаю какой( Хоть ткните носом в какой стороне искать.

Вот то, что я попробовал:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Builder.load_string('''
<OpenScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:(1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            id:bar_open
            orientation:'horizontal'
            padding:10
            spacing:10
            size_hint:(1,.1)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba:(0,0,1,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            Button:
                text:'Back'
                on_release:root.manager.current='main'
            Button:
                text:'Redact'
        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                id:content
                padding:10
                spacing:10
                orientation:'vertical'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height
''')


class OpenScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #Этот класс берёт строку,которая создается в другом классе(редакторе), и отрисовывает текст, а если
        #встречается путь к изображению({|image:path/to/pictures|}) то отрисовывает изображение
        self.string_of_text='''some text one
{|image:images/1.png|}
some text


two



{|image:images/3.png|}




some text else











abracadabara abracadabara abracadabara   abracadabara              abracadabara                  abracadabara








{|image:images/2.png|}

end
'''
        self.update_text(self.string_of_text)#вызываем функцию для создания виджетов


    def update_text(self,text):
        find_pic_start=text.find('{|image:')#Находим ключ отвечающий за изображение({|image:path/to/pictures|})
        if find_pic_start==-1:#если изображений нет, то просто отрисовываем текст
            self.ids.content.add_widget(Label(text=text,color=(0,0,0,1),text_size=(Window.width-25,None),
                                              size_hint_y=None,height=100))
        if find_pic_start!=-1:#если изображения есть, то...
            if find_pic_start==0:#если изображение это начало строки - рисуем изображение
                find_pic_end=text.find('|}')
                self.ids.content.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=text[8:find_pic_end],size_hint_y=None,height=50))
                text=text[find_pic_end+3:]#вырезаем путь из строки до текста

            if find_pic_start!=0:#если изображение это не начало строки - отрисовываем текст до изображения
                self.ids.content.add_widget(Label(text=text[:find_pic_start],color=(0,0,0,1),text_size=(Window.width-25,None),
                                              size_hint_y=None,height=100))
                text=text[find_pic_start:]#вырезаем текст из строки до изображения
            self.update_text(text)#вызываем функцию рекурсивно с новой урезанной строкой


class NoteApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(OpenScreen(name='open'))
        return sm


if __name__ =='__main__':
    NoteApp().run()
```

И то, что получил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы, чтобы последовательно друг за другом)

Comment: Экспериментировал с размерами. Если установить для каждого виджета отдельно его правильный размер вручную, то все располагается красиво. Но как задать програмно, чтобы определялись размеры для каждого виджета в автоматическом режиме, пока ещё в процессе поиска ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После некоторых попыток вот как всё вышло:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Builder.load_string('''
<OpenScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:(1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            id:bar_open
            orientation:'horizontal'
            padding:10
            spacing:10
            size_hint:(1,.1)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba:(0,0,1,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            Button:
                text:'Back'
                on_release:root.manager.current='main'
            Button:
                text:'Redact'
        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                id:content
                padding:10
                spacing:2
                orientation:'vertical'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height


<MyLabel>:
    height:self.texture_size[1]
''')


class MyLabel(Label):
    #в этом классе в kv файле задаётся высота текстового виджета
    #в зависимости от количества его строк, тоесть текстуры текста по высоте,
    #которая может достигать различных величин. Как сделать это python коде я
    #пока не знаю
    pass


class OpenScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #Этот класс берёт строку и отрисовывает текст, а если
        #встречается путь к изображению({|image:path/to/pictures|}) то отрисовывает изображение
        self.string_of_text='''
some text 1
{|image:images/1.jpg|}

***********************
Ваше благородие, госпожа разлука,
Мне с тобою холодно - вот какая штука.
Письмецо в конверте - погоди, не рви...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!
Письмецо в конверте погоди, не рви...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!

Ваше благородие, госпожа удача,
Для кого ты добрая, а кому - иначе.
Девять граммов в сердце, постой, не зови...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!
Девять граммов в сердце, постой, не зови...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!

Ваше благородие, госпожа чужбина,
Жарко обнимала ты, да только не любила.
В шёлковые сети постой, не лови...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!
В шёлковые сети постой, не лови...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!

Ваше благородие, госпожа победа,
Значит, моя песенка до конца не спета.
Перестаньте, черти, клясться на крови...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!
Перестаньте, черти, клясться на крови...
Не везет мне в смерти - повезет в любви!
***********************

{|image:images/2.jpg|}
О сколько нам открытий чудных
Готовят просвещенья дух
И опыт, сын ошибок трудных,
И гений, парадоксов друг,
И случай, бог изобретатель...
end
{|image:images/3.jpg|}
'''
        self.string_to_list=[]#этот список нужен для последовательной отрисовки объектов
        self.update_text(self.string_of_text)#вызываем функцию для создания виджетов


    def update_text(self,text):
        find_pic_start=text.find('{|image:')#Находим ключ отвечающий за изображение({|image:path/to/pictures|})
        if find_pic_start==-1:#если изображений нет, то просто отрисовываем текст
            self.string_to_list.append(text)#добавляем текст в список
            print('end!')
            self.create_widgets()

        if find_pic_start!=-1:#если изображения есть, то...
            if find_pic_start==0:#если изображение это начало строки - рисуем изображение
                find_pic_end=text.find('|}')
                self.string_to_list.append(text[:find_pic_end+3])#добавляем изображение в список
                text=text[find_pic_end+3:]#вырезаем путь из строки до текста

            if find_pic_start!=0:#если изображение это не начало строки - отрисовываем текст до изображения
                self.string_to_list.append(text[:find_pic_start])#добавляем текст в список
                text=text[find_pic_start:]#вырезаем текст из строки до изображения
            self.update_text(text)#вызываем функцию рекурсивно с новой урезанной строкой

    def create_widgets(self):#проходим элементы списка и в зависимости от содержимого рисуем соответствующий виджет
        for i in self.string_to_list:
            if '{|image:' in i:
                #пусть высота изображения будет зависима от высоты окна
                self.ids.content.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=i[8:-3],size_hint_y=None,height=(Window.height*0.4)))
            if '{|image:' not in i:
                #Используем собственный виджет MyLabel, у которого высота зависит от текстуры текста
                self.ids.content.add_widget(MyLabel(text=i,color=(0,0,0,1),text_size=(Window.width-25,None),
                                              size_hint_y=None))


class NoteApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(OpenScreen(name='open'))
        return sm


if __name__ =='__main__':
    NoteApp().run()
```

И вот результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]